# Import/export : netbeans for XMI

Tags: netbeans, xmi

i do followed an article to transform an UML activity diagram to BPEL , in one of the steps i found "SDE EE-NB Import" to import an XMI file , what does this mean.
[image]

This is the link of the article https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2674/a5619560a37536672972687f78227882bf6a.pdf

Comment: Could you please update your post to provide a link to the article you are following?

Comment: This is the link: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2674/a5619560a37536672972687f78227882bf6a.pdf

Comment: OK. My apologies if I am misunderstanding, but this isn't really an issue for SO since you don't appear to have a specific programming problem, and the article you linked to specifically explains what "SDE EE-NB Import" means: it allows you to import your **XMI** document into NetBeans so that the imported file can subsequently be used to generate BPEL from your original UML. Update the OP with a specific question if you have one.

Comment: i my netbeans i can't found "SDE EE-NB Import" , so i can't understand what does this mean

Answer (score 0):

Those menu entries are not part of standard NetBeans. You need to integrate **[Visual Paradigm](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/)** with NetBeans to get them.

From the link you provided:

> ***NetBeans enables the user to import the XMI file from the system and
>   generate the corresponding BPEL code accordingly***. Figure 3 describes
>   the methodology for transforming UML Functional Requirements into a
>   BPEL Specification.
>
> VP – UML is an environment where UML diagrams can be developed. ***But,
>   the UML modeling tool must be integrated with the NetBeans in order to
>   generate the BPEL specification***. Once the integration is successful,
>   XMI documents can be generated from the VP – UML and can be imported
>   into NetBeans...

Here are some [instructions on how to integrate Visual Paradigm and NetBeans](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/2381/2384/66569_overviewandi.html), though I don't know if that is the latest version.

Also, note that Visual Paradigm is a commercial product, and they only offer a free trial for 30 days.

---

Update based on clarification of the problem from the OP:

The [VP documentation](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/2381/2384/66569_overviewandi.html) specifically mentions what to do if the VP menu entries are missing in NetBeans after integration:

> NOTE: **If you cannot find any Visual Paradigm menus in NetBeans after
>   the installation, it could be due to our plug-in failed to be
>   recognized by NetBeans**. To solve this problem, please deactivate any
>   plug-in in NetBeans and restart NetBeans.
>
> You can manage plug-in in NetBeans by selecting Tools > Plugin in
>   NetBeans.

Also, you can check the NetBeans log for errors relating to Visual Paradigm and update your post with details of any relevant information. The log will be named **messages.log** and will reside under your NetBeans installation folder in the **log** folder. There may also be older logs named **messages.log.1**, **messages.log.2**, etc. which could contain relevant information.

Comment: i did integrate Visual Paradigm with NetBeans , and did not get them.

Comment: OK. I have updated my answer. It seems that NetBeans may not be recognizing the VP plugin.